# Variations of parameters in Scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and would like to know the differences between the following

```
define testFunc(par1: String) =  { }

define testFunc(par1: String)(par2: String) = {}

define testFunc(par1: String)(implicit par2: String) = {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def testFunc(par1: String) =  { }
```

A function (actually a method) that takes a `String` as its only parameter.

```
def testFunc(par1: String)(par2: String) = {}
```

A function (method) that takes two parameters, both of type `String`.  The parameters are [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Currying is interesting.  If you have a function that takes two curried arguments, and you call that function with only the first argument, what you get back is a new function that takes the other argument.

```
def testFunc(par1: String)(implicit par2: String) = {}
```

Same  as previous but if the 2nd parameter is not provided when the function is called then the compiler will look to see if a `String` that has been declared `implicit` is available.  If only one implicit string is in scope then that will be used as the 2nd parameter.

Note that this changes the curried aspect of the function in that it is an error if the implicit is not found or supplied.  You don't get the new function as before.